# Can I take rifle scope (scope only) in checked luggage to India

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, legal, india, firearms

I would like to visit India next month approximately between December 15-25 [ticket didn't taken yet]  from UAE Dubai. I have already purchased a telescope from Dubai market for my Indian air rifle. Can I take the rifle scope (not a rifle: just a 3-9x40 scope) with my luggage (check-in baggage)? In India will be there any problem with customs?

Comment: What problems are you worried about? Customs, duties, airlines? Or all of the above?

Comment: sir. i did not worried about duties but i need to know it is legal or illegal. if it is an offence i cant carry in my baggage.

Comment: Bro. have you face any issue in importing rifle scope to India with you...
I also want to bring one rifle scope with me to India from U. k. Will it be permissible

Answer (score 20):

### Rifle Scope Imports are *RESTRICTED*

India restricts the import of rifle scopes, as per [the list of restricted item downloaded from the Indian Directorate General of Foreign Trade website](http://dgft.gov.in/exim/2000/dn/ftpdnl/restrctd%20items.doc):

> ```
> +---------+------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
> | Item n. | Identifier |              Description              |   Status   |
> +---------+------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
> | 400.    | 9013 10 10 | Telescopic sights for fitting to arms | Restricted |
> +---------+------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
> ```

**Restricted items can be imported, provided one gets the appropriate authorisation from the governing bodies.** This is all explained in the [Foreign Trade Policy](http://dgft.gov.in/exim/2000/policy/ftp-plcontent-1011.htm), which can be downloaded from the [`Download` section of the Indian Directorate General of Foreign Trade website](http://dgft.gov.in/exim/2000/download-ftp1213.htm). It states:

> #### 2.07 Principles of Restrictions
>
> DGFT may, through a Notification, impose restrictions on export and import, necessary for: -
>
> 1. Protection of public morals;
> 2. Protection of human, animal or plant life or health;
> 3. Protection of patents, trademarks and copyrights, and
>      the prevention of deceptive practices;
> 4. Prevention of use of prison labour;
> 5. Protection of national treasures of artistic, historic or
>      archaeological value;
> 6. Conservation of exhaustible natural resources;
>      33
> 7. Protection of trade of fissionable material or material
>      from which they are derived;
> 8. Prevention of traffic in arms, ammunition and
>      implements of war.
>
> #### 2.08 Export/Import of Restricted goods/Services
>
> Any goods /service, the export or import of which is ‘Restricted’ may be exported or imported only in accordance with an Authorisation / Permission or in accordance with the procedure prescribed in a Notification / Public Notice issued in this regard.
>
> [...]
>
> #### 2.11 Terms and Conditions of an Authorisation
>
> Every Authorisation shall, inter alia, include following
>   terms and conditions (as applicable), in addition to such
>   other conditions as may be specified: (Amended vide
>   Notification No 8/2015-20 dated 4th June, 2015)
>   1. Description, quantity and value of goods;
>   1. Actual User condition (as defined in Chapter 9);
>   1. Export Obligation;
>   1. Minimum Value addition to be achieved;
>   1. Minimum export/import price;
>   1. Bank guarantee/ Legal undertaking / Bond with
>   1. Customs Authority/RA (as in para 2. 35 of FTP).
>   1. Validity period of import/export as specified in Handbook of Procedures.
>
> #### 2.12 Application Fee
>
> Application for IEC/ Authorisation / License / Scrips must be accompanied by application fees as indicated in the Appendix 2K of Appendices and Aayat Niryat Forms.
>
> [...]
>
> #### 2.14 Authorisation - not a Right
>
> No person can claim an Authorisation as a right and DGFT or RA shall have power to refuse to grant or renew the same in accordance with provisions of FT (D&R) Act, Rules made there under and FTP.

#### Reading Material

The web is scattered with forum threads on rifle scope imports in India. One useful reference is [this thread from Indian For Guns](http://www.indiansforguns.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=3812) which roughly states what I have paraphrased above.

#### Legal Concerns

It is worthy to note that [people have been previously arrested for attempting to illegally import rifle scopes in India](http://www.dnaindia.com/mumbai/report-37-year-old-held-for-illegally-importing-rifle-scopes-in-mumbai-1451796). Granted that was an extreme case, but personally I would be wary of people online telling you to go ahead and put the scope in your hand luggage because you are unlikely to be checked by customs. Smuggling restricted items is a serious offence, and if caught you will be prosecuted.

Comment: +1 For excellent research. Probably a good idea to be careful in general with gun parts. Things as innocuous as a simple spring, if intended for a firearm, can be controlled goods both for **export** and for **import**, and the authorities are not necessarily forgiving if the necessary licenses have not been procured.

Comment: Several of the links don't work anymore...

Comment: Importing 100 scopes is quiet different than one, but it's still restricted nonetheless.

Answer (score -6):

[Without having experience from travelling in that part of the world] I would say you should be fine. It is not a weapon, not a sharp object, or any other forbidden object? If you want you could contact the airport/airline you are planning to travel to/with to ask them.

Comment: I'd pack that in a hard case though, transporting good quality glass in checked luggage would make me nervous